# Flex - How to display Tree like view of file system?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I need a view of file system like this.

```
folder_name    
|_sub_folder1
|  |_file1
|  |_file2
|_sub_folder2
   |_file1
```

please give your comments.

Comment: is this Java server - Flex client application bridge ? or It is Flex ( AIR ) application working on top of Java framework ( like Android ) ?

Answer (score 1):

What does Flex have to do with your question?

You already asked this question and got your answer: use a tree. Furthermore, you don't say whether you want to process the structure (run through it), store it in memory, or whether you want to visually display the tree.

If you're putting it into memory, create a node-based tree where each `Node` has a `List` of `Node`s. Each node's value is a `String` containing the file name. Below is an example. I suggest coming up with something a little more usable. You could use the JTree API or the DOM API, but I recommend creating a tree from scratch because it has a much smaller memory footprint.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tree<String> t = new Tree<>();

        Tree.Node<String> usr = new Tree.Node<>("/usr");
        Tree.Node<String> home = new Tree.Node<>("/home");
        Tree.Node<String> share = new Tree.Node<>("/share");
        Tree.Node<String> docs = new Tree.Node<>("/documents");

        t.root = new Tree.Node<>("/");
        t.root.children.add(usr);
        t.root.children.add(home);

        usr.children.add(share);
        home.children.add(docs);
    }
}

class Tree<T> {

    Node<T> root;

    static class Node<T> {

        T file;
        List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();

        Node(T file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help but this code is not properly working. It throws NullPointerException at line "t.root.children.add(usr);" kindly reply me with the appropriate solution. I'll be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Flex in a browser will not give you access to any file system information, only AIR projects will allow you to access files and directories.

Now, if you're just trying to create a tree, I've found the easiest is to make your own object, with an array property "children" that will automatically be used by the flex tree control to display subnodes.

so:

```
<mx:Tree id="treeProducts" labelField="productName" 
         dataProvider="{_productList}">
</mx:Tree>
```

where:

```
[Bindable]
var _productList:ArrayCollection;
```

and for each object you put into _productList, it needs:

```
tmpObject.children = new ArrayCollection();
```